# Function to set a 2 byte register

Tags: c, atmega

I would like to know if there is an AVR builtin function which helps you setting a two bytes register once you pass an int value.

Example:
I need an alarm clock to be set at 15600 clocks (1 second on a 1MHz microprocessor).

In order to do so I need to set it as follows:

```
//Alarm clock at 15600 clocks
OCR0A = 0b11110000;
OCR0B = 0b00111100;
```

Since ATMEGA's AVR library has some cool builtin functions (like setting a bit) I would like to know if there is one I just give an int and it sets the two bytes accordingly.

Comment: ATmega does not have **any** builtin functions! It is a CPU architecture and executes machine code. It does not even have a concept of _functions_. What is the problem writing your own "set_alarm" function in C, though? It would have been typed faster that posting that question.

Comment: did you try 'sbr' opcode (see the following link : http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_SBR.html)

Comment: @Zohar81: You confuse C and Assembler. (much like OP seems to)

Comment: Why so negative Olaf? :-)

Comment: The older we get, the grouchier we get `:)`

Comment: @Bob: Where am I negative? I think this is quite a correct diagnosis. Diagnosing a problem is the first step to solving it. Oh, and prefix nicks with `@`, otherwise the addressee likely will not be notified.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf +1 for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all C compiler allow for inline assembler code that is not going to be optimized. If you use `avrgcc` you find a very detailled tutorial here: [AVR GCC Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html). So you can directly get down to the assembler code of the controller. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to load a word directly from flash memory to a register pair. But you could preload a different register pair and use the [MOVW (Move Word)](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_MOVW.html) command to move its value to the destination register pair.

If you just want to use `avrgcc` without drilling down to assembler and your aim is to load a register pair in an atomic access (to prevent interupt interruption) you can use the ATOMIC_BLOCK pragma. Additionally the `avr-libc` defines for some 16-bit registers a single byte access. To load the `Timer/Counter Output Compare Register` you could use:

```
ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE)
{
    //Alarm clock at 15600 clocks
    OCR1A = 0x3cf0;
}
```